# Simple Lagrange interpolation

Tags: c++, object-oriented, mathematics, c++14

I wrote a Lagrange polynomial interpolation class. It works fine. At the beginning some definitions:
$$
\begin{align}
&nodes:\qquad x_0, \dots, x_n \\
&values:\qquad f(x_0), \dots, f(x_n) \\
&weights:\qquad w_0, \dots, w_n\qquad\text{where}~~~ w_j = \prod_{k=0, k \neq j}^{n}(x_j-x_k)^{-1} \\
&coeff:\qquad f(x_0)w_0, \dots, f(x_n)w_n.
\end{align}
$$

Let's denote $$c_i = f(x_i)w_i.$$
Value of approximation at some point is equal to
$$
\begin{align}
p(x) = l(x) \sum_{i=0}^{n} c_i(x-x_i)^{-1}, \qquad \text{where}~~l(x) = \prod_{i=0}^{n}(x-x_i).
\end{align}
$$

Code (firstly `lagrange_interpolation.h`):

```
#include <vector>
#include <valarray>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <numeric>

template<typename T, typename V>
int binary_search_find_index(const std::vector<T> &v, V data) {
    std::size_t index = 0;
    auto it = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), data);
    if (it == v.end() || *it != data) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        index = std::distance(v.begin(), it);
    }   
    return index;
}

class LInter {
typedef std::vector<double> vector;
public:
    LInter(vector nodes, vector values) {
        if (nodes.empty() || values.empty()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("one of the vector is empty");
        }
    
        std::vector<int> indices(nodes.size());
        std::iota(indices.begin(), indices.end(), 0);
        std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end(),[&](int a, int b) -> bool {
            if (nodes[a] == nodes[b]) {
                throw std::invalid_argument("nodes are not unique");
            }
            return nodes[a] < nodes[b]; }
        );
    
        if (nodes.size() != values.size()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("sizes of vectors differ");
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
            std::swap(nodes[i], nodes[indices[i]]);
            std::swap(values[i], values[indices[i]]);
        }
        nodes_ = nodes;
        values_ = values;
        poly_deg_ = nodes_.size() - 1;
        GenerateWeights();
        GenerateCoefficients();
    }
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, double> operator()(T);
  
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::valarray<double>>  
    operator()(T const &);
 
private:
    vector nodes_;
    vector values_;
    vector weights_;
    vector coeff_;
    unsigned poly_deg_;
    void GenerateWeights(void);
    void GenerateCoefficients(void);
};
```

and `lagrange_interpolation.cc`:

````
#include "lagrange_interpolation.h"
#include <type_traits>

void LInter::GenerateWeights(void) {
    int size = poly_deg_ + 1;
    weights_.insert(weights_.begin(), size, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (i != j) {
                weights_[i] *= (nodes_[i] - nodes_[j]);
            }
        }
        weights_[i] = 1/weights_[i];
    }
}

void LInter::GenerateCoefficients(void) {
    int size = poly_deg_ + 1;
    coeff_.insert(coeff_.begin(), size, 1);
    std::transform(values_.begin(), values_.end(), weights_.begin(), coeff_.begin(), [](double v, double w) { return v*w;});
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, double> LInter::operator()(T x) {
    auto index = binary_search_find_index(nodes_, x);
    if (index != -1) { 
        return values_[index];
    }
    double polynomial = 1;
    for (auto node : nodes_) {
        polynomial *= (x - node);
    }
    double result = std::inner_product(coeff_.begin(), coeff_.end(), nodes_.begin(), 0.0, std::plus<>(),[&](double &a, double &b) { return a/(x - b); });
    result *= polynomial;
    return result;
}

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, std::valarray<double>> 
    LInter::operator()(T const &input) {
    std::valarray<double> result(input.size());
    std::transform(std::begin(input), std::end(input), std::begin(result), 
    [this](double x) { return operator()(x); } );
    return result;
}
```
````

Comment: Could someone edit my post and change coeff to \text{coeff} (and other) in align enviroment? Unfortunately I can't do this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## binary_search_find_index

I'm not sure why you are using different template types for the `vector` and `data`.

It looks like you are trying to find the index of the **closest** element in the vector but then you discard it if it's not exactly equal to `data`

```
if (it == v.end() || *it != data) {
    return -1;
} else ...
```

Perhaps this is closer to what you initially intended to do:

```
if (it == v.end() || std::abs(*it - data) > someVerySmallNumber {
    return -1;
} else...
```

Since I cannot really guess what your intentions were, I will just assume that you are trying to get the index of an element in an array.

First I would change the return type to `std::size_t` which is the correct type for array size and indexes. You can also use `std::optional<std::size_t>` and `std::find` like the following:

```
template<typename T>
std::optional<std::size_t> binary_search_find_index(const std::vector<T>& v, T data) {
    auto index = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), data);
    if (index == v.end())
        return std::nullopt;
    return index - v.begin();
}
```

Then you can use `binary_search_find_index` like so:

```
void test() {
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    auto index = binary_search_find_index(v, 3);
    if (index == std::nullopt)
        std::cout << "item is not in array.\n";
    else
        std::cout << "index = " << *index << '\n';
}
```

Since you are only using `binary_search_find_index` in one location, I think it might be better to actually remove it from the program and rather change `::operator()(T x)` to the following:

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<T>, double> LInter<T>::operator()(T x) {
    auto node = std::find(nodes_.begin(), nodes_.end(), x);
    if (node != nodes_.end()) {
        return *node;
    }
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

## LInter

I would have rather templated the class instead of using `typedef std::vector<double> vector;`.

Consider changing to the following:

```
template<class T>
class LInter {
public:
    LInter(std::vector<T> nodes, std::vector<T> values) {
        if (nodes.empty() || values.empty()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("one of the vector is empty");
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also note that `poly_deg_` should be `std::size_t poly_deg_` instead of simply `unsigned poly_deg_`

## Test cases

Reviewing the code would have been easier and more productive if you included some test cases.